# SQL Select unique values in 1 column

Tags: sql

I've got problem (a little problem I suppose) and I hope, you'll help me.
I use Sybase Anywhere and here's my code:

```
SELECT TOP 4 Person.Id_person, Person.Name, Person.Surname, Visit.Date, Visit.Place
From Person, Visit
WHERE Visit.Id_person = Person.Id_person
ORDER BY Visit.DATE DESC
```

and here's the result:

```
3  | Paul | McDonald | 2010-01-19 | Ohio
3  | Paul | McDonald | 2010-01-18 | New York
19 | Ted  | Malicky  | 2009-12-24 | Tokyo
12 | Meg  | Newton   | 2009-10-13 | Warsaw
```

and I would like not to duplicate Paul McDonald, and have only first (by the date) visit. I'd like to have result like this:

```
3  | Paul | McDonald | 2010-01-19 | Ohio
19 | Ted  | Malicky  | 2009-12-24 | Tokyo
12 | Meg  | Newton   | 2009-10-13 | Warsaw
 ....
```

What should I do? Could you help me? :(

Comment: I don't know sybase *specifically*, but in many databases you'd either have to group by day taking the min and then re-expand, or use an extra `WHERE` condition to filter out additional bookings for the same person.

Comment: @Alliah: for the Visit table, is (Id_Person, Date) unique?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a different way to do it using the ROW_NUMBER function to ensure that if someone has two meetings on the same day it still works:

```
SELECT TOP 4
    Person.Id_person,
    Person.Name,
    Person.Surname,
    T1.Date,
    T1.Place
FROM
    (SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id_person ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rn
    FROM Visit) AS T1
JOIN Person
ON T1.Id_person = Person.Id_person
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Here's the result I get:

```
Id_person Name Surname  Date       Place
3         Paul McDonald 2010-01-19 Ohio
19        Ted  Malicky  2009-12-24 Tokyo
12        Meg  Newton   2009-10-13 Warsaw
1         Foo  Bar      2009-06-03 Someplace
```

Here's the test data I used:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (Id_person INT NOT NULL, Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, Surname NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Person (Id_person, Name, Surname) VALUES
(3, 'Paul', 'McDonald'),
(19, 'Ted', 'Malicky'),
(12, 'Meg', 'Newton'),
(1, 'Foo', 'Bar'),
(2, 'Baz', 'Qux');

CREATE TABLE Visit (Id_person INT NOT NULL, Date DATE NOT NULL, Place NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Visit (Id_person, Date, Place) VALUES
(3, '2010-01-19', 'Ohio'),
(3, '2010-01-18', 'New York'),
(19, '2009-12-24', 'Tokyo'),
(12, '2009-10-13', 'Warsaw'),
(1, '2009-06-03', 'Someplace'),
(12, '2009-10-13', 'Anotherplace'),
(2, '2009-05-04', 'Somewhere');
```

Tested on SQL Server 2008, but I believe the syntax for Sybase is similar.

Comment: One person can be in two places at the same time? :)

Comment: @Andomar: No... same *date*, not same time. You can't be in two places at the same time, but theoretically you could make two different visits on the same day, possibly even to different cities.

Comment: If you use a DateTime field then the solution if quite a bit simpler.

Comment: @Mark Brittingham: The OP's table appears to use a Date column, so I did too. Presumably they don't record visits on a second-by-second basis, but just store the date.

Comment: I think you deserve extra points for even providing the samples tables and their data.

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier way and it'll show you the most recent trip for each person as well:

```
SELECT TOP 4 Person.Id_person, Person.Name, Person.Surname, Visit.Date, Visit.Place 
  From Person, Visit 
  WHERE Visit.Id_person = Person.Id_person 
      AND (Visit.[Date] = (Select Max([Date]) 
                            From Visit Where (Person.Id_person=Visit.Id_Person)))
  ORDER BY Visit.DATE DESC
```

I use a variant of this quite often in my work.  The only caveat is that the "Date" field in the visit table is a DateTime (and, of course, that someone can't be in two places at the same time).

Comment: Note that this solution also assumes (Id_Person, Date) is unique on the Visit table. This might be a valid assumption, but the OP didn't specify it. I've commented on the question, asking the OP to clarify this.

Comment: @Mark Byers - that's why I included in my caveat that someone can't be in two places at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `where not exists` clause to filter out earlier visits:

```
SELECT TOP 4 p1.Id_person, p1.Name, p1.Surname, v1.Date, v1.Place
FROM Person p1, Visit v1
WHERE p1.Id_person = v1.Id_person
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    From Person p2, Visit v2
    WHERE v2.Id_person = p2.Id_person
    AND p1.Id_person = p2.Id_person
    AND v2.Date > v1.Date
)
ORDER BY v1.DATE DESC
```

To improve readability, consider rewriting the double `from` as a join.  For example, change:

```
FROM Person v1, Visit v1
WHERE v1.Id_person = p1.Id_person
```

into:

```
FROM Person p1
INNER JOIN Visit v1 ON v1.Id_person = p1.Id_person
```

Comment: @Alliah: Note that this solution assumes that (Id_Person, Date) is unique on the visit table. If that is the case, use this solution. If not, this will produce duplicates.

Comment: @Andomar: I tested this in SQL Server and it failed because "Visit.Id_person = Person.Id_person" should be "v1.Id_person = p1.Id_person". But maybe it works in Sybase, I don't know. Just mentioning it in case it helps.

Comment: @Mark: Obviously a typo and corrected.  No need for the "it might work in Sybase" charade tho. :P